# Does 'of' mean 'to be'?

Tags: grammaticality, legalese, phrasal-verbs

[[Source:]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slaughter-House_Cases) Majority opinion, *Slaughter-House Cases*, 1873, by Justice [Samuel Freeman Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Freeman_Miller) .

> We think `this distinction and its explicit recognition in this Amendment`
>    **of** great weight in this argument

I'm guessing that the preposition **of** can be replaced with the infinitive 'to be'.
Even if so, and despite this diction from 1873, does this use match any  definition in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130549?rskey=ZuocQi&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)?
Though I read entirely the OED's lengthy entry for **of**, its 60 definitions overwhelm me.
So how can I determine which definition matches?

I recognise this diction to date to 1873. Also, **of** is a [particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb#Some_notes_on_terminology) here (and NOT a preposition) because **of** is separated from the verb 'think' by the noun phrase coloured in grey.

Comment: I think when you reach law school you **will be** expected to explore readings in their entirety, or at least until you find the information you are seeking.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks. I meant to state that I don't expect others to read the entire page just for me, but I clarified in my OP now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Of* here is employed in OED's sense XIV.47:

> **XIV.** Indicating a quality or other distinguishing mark by which a person or thing is characterized, identified or described.
>   <sup>Used for the Old English genitive, French *de*; equivalent to the genitive of quality or description.</sup>
>
> **47.** Indicating a quality possessed by the subject.
>   <sup>The quality is usually expressed by a noun qualified by an adjective, but may consist of a noun alone, as in ‘a man of tact’, ‘a text-book of authority’. It is often equivalent to an adjective as in ‘a man of tact’ = a tactful man, ‘a work of authority’ = an authoritative work.</sup>

The preposition phrase is employed adjectivally. It is most often encountered as an attributive set immediately after the noun modified, as it is in *OED*'s examples above; but it may also be deployed as a predicative<sup>†</sup>, as it is in your example.

> We think this distinction [...] of great weight.

The construction with *think* is the same as in *We think this distinction important*, *We think this distinction trivial*, *We think this distinction a red herring*. You may insert *to be* at this point (*We think this distinction [...]to be of great weight*), but it does not replace *of*, which is critical to the sense.

---

<sup>†</sup> Here are some of *OED*'s citations with the preposition phrase employed predicatively.

> ?c1430  (▸c1400)    Wyclif *Eng. Wks.* (1880) 201   It is of most auctorite.
>   a1500  (▸?c1400)    *Sir Triamour* (Cambr.) (1937) 868   Syr Barnard was of myght.
>   1512   *Act 4 Hen. VIII* c. 4 §1   To be utterly voyde and of noo force ne effect.
>   1560   J. Daus tr. J. *Sleidane* Commentaries f. xix,   He is still of the same minde.
>   1966   N. Gordimer *Late Bourgeois World* 66   The jobs came last in any consideration because they were of no importance.

Answer (score 1):

I think by looking at "of", you're looking at the wrong word, and should be looking at "think" instead.

[From Merriam-Webster:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/think)

> **think**
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> **3 b :** to regard as **:** CONSIDER <*think* the rule unfair>

Notice that the example they give means the same thing as

> think the rule **to be** unfair

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing that the preposition 'of' can be replaced with the
>   infinitive 'to be'.

This is ellipsis of the verb-to-be.  *think* and *consider* and *hold* and *regard* take a direct object followed by a complement which can be a to-infinitive phrase.

**We hold these truths to be self-evident**.

Over time, the "to be" is [gets dropped](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(think+it+to+be+the)%2C(think+it+the)&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28think%20it%20to%20be%20the%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28think%20it%20the%29%3B%2Cc0):

**We think this (to be) unfair.**

**We think this (to be) of no great significance.**